# Family of graphs where each vertex has a constant number of independent neighbors

Tags: graph-theory

A question for graph theory experts. Consider a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices that has the following property: each vertex in $G$ has at most $c$ independent neighbors for some constant $c$.

Do the graphs with the above property have a name? Have they been studied? Obviously for $c=1$ , $G$ has to be a collection of cliques.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you will find something on these links : [Glossary of Graph Theory - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory) and [Gallery of named graphs - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $c=2$, these are the [claw-free graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph), which have been well-studied; the motivation for looking at these is that any [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) is claw-free.

In general, the graphs you describe could be called the (induced) $K_{1,c+1}$-free graphs. I don't think there's a more concise name.